# .NET Core 7.0 how to Pass static parameter

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, asp.net-core-7.0

I currently working for the UI part, I would like to create a template html to use it globally for every pages.

I would like to know how to pass a static text string to view components:

`ViewComponent/PageHeaderViewComponent.cs`

```
public class InvokeRequest
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}

[ViewComponent(Name = "PageHeader")]
public class PageHeaderViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(InvokeRequest request)
        
    {
        return View("Index", request);
    }
}
```

`Views/Shared/Components/PageHeader/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model string

<div id="SomeTemplateTest">
    <p>@Model.A</p>
    <h1>@Model.B</h1>
    <h1>@Model.C</h1>
    <h1>@Model.D</h1>
</div>
```

`Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

```
<body>
...
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PageHeader", new InvokeRequest(){ A = Model.A, B = "B", C = Model.C, D = Model.D, E = "2" })
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only little modification of your codes will work. You can try the following:
`ViewComponent/PageHeaderViewComponent.cs` the same as yours
`Views/Shared/Components/PageHeader/Index.cshtml`.change the `string` to `InvokeRequest`

```
@model WebApplication76.ViewComponents.InvokeRequest

<div id="SomeTemplateTest">
    <p>@Model.A</p>
    <h1>@Model.B</h1>
    <h1>@Model.C</h1>
    <h1>@Model.D</h1>
</div>
```

`Views/Shared/Components/PageHeader/Index.cshtml`. Also add`InvokeRequest` as @model

```
@model WebApplication76.ViewComponents.InvokeRequest
@using WebApplication76.ViewComponents;  //here you also need to refence the view components invoke method namespace
...
<body>
...
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PageHeader", new InvokeRequest(){ A = Model.A, B = "B", C = Model.C, D = Model.D, E = "2" })
...
</body>
```

`Controllers/HomeController.cs`.  you need to pass model value to the main page you visit.

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model= new InvokeRequest() { A="A",C="C",D="D"};
            return View(model);
        }
```

Output
[image]

An easy way to auto fix unreferenced item
[image]

Comment: I have an error with: The type or namespace name 'WebApplication76' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Kelvin Webapplication76 is my project name, you need to change to yours. And It is the namespace where InvokeRequest located.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'AppToolbarItemName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). But i already change the InvokeRequest to  AppToolbarItemName and included @model PROJECTNAME.Controllers.AppToolbarItemName

Comment: If i put PROJECTNAME.ViewComponents.AppToolbarItemName it show The type or namespace name 'ViewComponents' does not exist in the namespace.

Comment: @Kelvin you need also reference the method namespace with '@using " , I update the answer of layout

Comment: @Kelvin You can also see the screenshot in the end to fix reference problems.

Comment: Thank @qiang-fu , but how if i want to use the string as HTML?

Comment: @Kelvin Do you mean this `<p>@Html.Raw(Model.A)</p>`

Comment: what i mean is model.a = {HTML}, because maybe some pages need extra html

Comment: @Kelvin Yes, it is the same. You can use `@Html.Raw({html})` in the razor page to output html from string.